# How to add a Cordova resource file (custom ringtone) in a Meteor app

Tags: cordova, meteor

How to add a `resource-file` to a Meteor Cordova iOS app?

I'm using the [CordovaCall plugin](https://github.com/WebsiteBeaver/CordovaCall). 
I've added the ringtone file in `cordova-build-override/` and used `App.appendToConfig(element)` to declare the `resource-file` in `mobile-config.js`.

But get an error when meteor run ios-device:

```
=> Errors executing Cordova commands:         

   While adding platform iOS to Cordova project:
   Error: Source path does not exist: all_that_she_wants_i.caf
(...)
```

Looks like Meteor reads `config.xml` before copying the ringtone file to the `cordova-build` directory.

Is there any straightforward way to do this in Meteor?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feature you are looking for is currently under development and will be ready with `Meteor v1.7` which will be released very soon. You can see the related ticket [here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/9748). In the meantime, you may upload your resource files to the `Resources`folder via `Xcode` as illustrated in the following picture.

[image]